# Connecting to newly created database after previous connection error

Tags: sql-server

My application is periodically connecting to MyDatabase and performing a query.

I need to handle the case where the MyDatabase database does not already exist and needs to be created. What I am doing currently is each time I first connect to the master database and run something like this:

`SELECT * FROM sysdatabases WHERE NAME='MyDatabase'`

to determine whether MyDatabase exists. If it doesn't I create it and then proceed with connecting to MyDatabase and performing the query.

Opening a separate connection to the master database and performing a query each time seems unnecessary (even though the connections are pooled). Why can't I just connect to MyDatabase straight away? 99% of the time it will succeed and I can execute the queries. The 1% of times it fails I can detect MyDatabase is missing and create it at that point right?

But when I try this I hit a problem. If I attempt to connect to MyDatabase and it doesn't exist I get a SqlException

> Cannot open database MyDatabase requested by the login. The login failed.

Fine. Great. I can catch any SqlException and then go off to the master database to determine MyDatabase does not exist and create it.

But after creating it, when I now try to connect to MyDatabase I **immediately** get the same error:

> Cannot open database MyDatabase requested by the login. The login failed.

It looks like it isn't trying to connect again and instead is returning a cached result. If I wait 10 seconds after creating the database before attempting to connect to it, the connection succeeds.

My question is, is this caching expected (I guess so) and more importantly is there a best practice for dealing with this situation? Is there perhaps a cache clearance or timeout setting in the SqlConnection API I can use? I could implement my own timeout delay I think but I would like to know there isn't a better method I am missing.

Comment: How long does it take to create your database?  Is it just that the files are currently being created on the server and the DB isn't actually ready yet?

Comment: It creates almost instantly. I've tried creating and connecting without a previous error and it worked fine. The behavior is different if a previous connection failed. In that case if I try to connect again within about 10 seconds you get the same error back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.

When I call the static [`SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools(v=vs.110).aspx) method before I try to open the newly created database, it works fine!

Comment: think I remember this working, although in my case it one small component in a bigger system that needed to do this, so there was some debate whether wiping the entire connection pool was acceptable.