# Wait for creation database to finish

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I have a code like this:

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  sqlConnection.Open();
  using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(scriptText, sqlConnection))
  {
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

For the first time I call it to create a DB, then I form a connection string to this DB and try to do some work (`Open` works fine and says the connection is actually open for this second connection). But I get an "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" and I can see the sql logs "Could not find database ID 9. Database may not be activated yet or may be in transition". So, actually the `ExecuteNonQuery` return before the job is done. Sure, I can just spam it until a situation changes, but is there a better way to wait for DB to be ready for work?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery should be waiting until it is complete. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Comment: @Shawn, I thought so. Seems, it doesn't.

Comment: are you sure the database is being created correctly?

Comment: @Shawn, Yes, later it works perfectly. `IF NOT EXISTS (Select * from sys.databases where name = N'{0}') CREATE DATABASE [{0}]`

Comment: how big is the database? Maybe it's timing out?

Comment: @Shawn, it's empty. I've listed the only code that executes by the first `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This complete sample works for me.

It creates the database, creates a table, puts a row in the table.

Not sure what is wrong on your end.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace GranadaCoder.PlaygroundConsole.SqlStuff
{
    public class SqlPlayground
    {

        public static void EntryPointStuff()
        {
            string databaseName = "MyFirstDatabaseABC";
            string connectionString = string.Empty;
            string commandText = string.Empty;
            int returnValue = 0;
            string msg = string.Empty;

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder["Initial Catalog"] = "master";
            builder["integrated Security"] = true;
            builder["Server"] = @"MyMachine\MyInstance";
            connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;


            commandText = string.Format("IF EXISTS (Select * from sys.databases where name = N'{0}') DROP DATABASE [{0}]", databaseName);
            returnValue = RunACommand(connectionString, commandText);
            msg = string.Format("'{0}', {1}", returnValue, commandText);
            Console.WriteLine(msg);

            commandText = string.Format("IF NOT EXISTS (Select * from sys.databases where name = N'{0}') CREATE DATABASE [{0}]", databaseName);
            returnValue = RunACommand(connectionString, commandText);
            msg = string.Format("'{0}', {1}", returnValue, commandText);
            Console.WriteLine(msg);

            /* Change the Catalog */
            builder["Initial Catalog"] = databaseName;
            connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;


            commandText = "if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[CodeCategory]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)    BEGIN       DROP TABLE [dbo].[CodeCategory]     END ";
            returnValue = RunACommand(connectionString, commandText);
            msg = string.Format("'{0}', {1}", returnValue, commandText);
            Console.WriteLine(msg);

            commandText = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CodeCategory] (    CodeCategoryKey           [smallint] not null     , CodeCategoryName      varchar(64) not null  ) ";
            returnValue = RunACommand(connectionString, commandText);
            msg = string.Format("'{0}', {1}", returnValue, commandText);
            Console.WriteLine(msg);


            commandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[CodeCategory] (     CodeCategoryKey       , CodeCategoryName    ) Select 1001 , 'MyFirstCodeCategory' ";
            returnValue = RunACommand(connectionString, commandText);
            msg = string.Format("'{0}', {1}", returnValue, commandText);
            Console.WriteLine(msg);

            commandText = "Select Count(*) from [dbo].[CodeCategory]";
            returnValue = RunACommand(connectionString, commandText);
            msg = string.Format("'{0}', {1}", returnValue, commandText);
            Console.WriteLine(msg);

        }




        private static int RunACommand(string connectionString, string scriptText)
        {

            int returnValue = 0;

            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(scriptText, sqlConnection))
                {
                    returnValue = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }

            return returnValue;
        }






    }

}
```

This works for me (with no exceptions):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {

            SqlPlayground.EntryPointStuff();

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter after deleting the database in SSMS manually with 'Close Existing Connections' checked.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            SqlPlayground.EntryPointStuff();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Pressing Enter To End");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: Note how I change the "Initial Catalog" after I create the database.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried it and it's works. Still, if I call the `EntryPointStuff` twice and between these calls I manually delete the db with a "close existing connections" I get exactly the same problem as I've explained in my question. Seems like this is actually my test case.

Comment: I appended some extra info.  I don't get the behavior you describe.

Comment: I've found that it is a connection pooling issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134166/how-to-guard-a-pooled-connection

Answer (score 2):

In my case [adding Thread.Sleep(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123094/wait-for-creation-database-to-finish/33995169#33995169) helped, but the **root** cause was that the failed connection was cached and used by method SqlConnection.Open(). See [answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569844/connecting-to-newly-created-database-after-previous-connection-error) for this situation. [Clearing the pool with SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools(v=vs.110).aspx) helps.

Why then waiting for some seconds helps too? Seems that it was enough to clear the pool automatically by timer.

Comment: SqlConnection.ClearAllPools() cleared this up for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may notice this problem if you are doing someting else immediately(e.g. updating database schema) following the creation. Waiting for a few seconds seems to solve the problem.

```
//wait for database creation
Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

Comment: And "3s" is an officially specified and guaranteed by every OS, database, network environment, etc. timeframe for a database to be created, right? And, sure, nowdays we all know very well how stupid and useless multithreading and asynchronousity and it's very easy to make sure that some code in your programm will not get executed if a thread is sleeping.

Comment: @aush I never made those claims. There wasn't multithreading in my case so it worked for me. This will work for the most cases but do do not use it for life critical systems :)

Comment: In my case adding `Thread.Sleep(...)` helped, but the root cause was that the cached failed connection was used by method `SqlConnection.Open()`.
See [answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569844/connecting-to-newly-created-database-after-previous-connection-error) for this situation.

[Clearing the pool with  SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools(v=vs.110).aspx) helped. 
Why then waiting for someseconds helped? Seems that it was enough to clear the pool automatically.

Comment: thanks @flam3, had the exact same issue and clearing the pool helped. Could you add this as an answer?