# How to guard a pooled connection?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, connection, connection-pooling

In my app I work with a sql-server and connections are pooled by .net. What is a good practice to guard such a case:

> Connections in the pool might be reset by any reason (network, DBA kill the session, etc). In those cases, SQL Server does close the connection, but SQL Client does not know anything about it. When a physically closed connection get re-assigned. You will not get error when you open the connection, this is different from opening a non-pooled connection. The error will arise when the first command is executed.

Sure, this situation is *exceptional*, so it's natural to try-catch it, but maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: Link the quote where it is from

Comment: @SriramSakthivel presumably http://www.sqlnotes.info/2012/02/01/few-things-about-pooled-connections/

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes a google with some text lead to to this article :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try` / `catch` is the appropriate approach in this case. You are trying to deal with an action that is basically not in your control, which would cause an error situation in your application at identifiable junctures (when retrieving data). This is exactly what `try` and `catch` are there for.